# Utilizar una Query de SQL como fuente de un Modelo en Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql, entity-framework-6

Buen día!

Les comento, estoy teniendo la necesidad de agregar un Modelo en EF, pero con la peculiaridad de que use una **Query** de SQL como fuente de información en lugar de una tabla.

Intenté hacerlo por las vías normales de la siguiente manera

```
[Table("[dbo].[ViewCuboVenta]")]
public class CuboVentas
{
    [Key]
    [Column("[ClienteRazon]",Order = 2)]
    public string Cliente { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("[NumeroCotizacion]",Order = 0)]
    public string Nota_de_Venta { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("[ArtiCodiCompuesto]",Order = 1)]
    public string Cod_Fabricacion { get; set; }
}
```

El asunto es que salta una excepción diciendo que ninguna de mis columnas existe.

> SqlException: Invalid column name '[NumeroCotizacion]'.
>   Invalid column name '[NumeroCotizacion]'.
>   Invalid column name '[ArtiCodiCompuesto]'.
>   Invalid column name '[ClienteRazon]'.

El tema de consultar a una query es una obligación, ya que no tengo acceso a la base de datos completa, sino sólo a algunas Query, y necesitaría esta para utilizarla como Repositorio, (tener el nombre del cliente, cotización y artículo comprado)

Aclaro que al ser una Query en realidad no posee Claves primarias en la base de datos, pero si no lo armo como una clave compuesta voy a tener repitencia de claves primarias en el modelo

¿Existe manera de hacerlo con un DBContext? o directamente la solución es realizar la consulta de modo convencional?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Cuando dices una query, te refieres a un Stored Procedure? a una Vista? a una función?. Puedes poner un ejemplo de una de las Querys que tienes disponible?

Comment: Creo que en tu caso, lo único disponible es simplemente generar objetos que sean específicos para cada consulta, y poblarlos con las respectivas consultas

Comment: Que exactamente es una query? Store procedure?

Answer (score 0):

analizando la descripción de tu pregunta entiendo que te dieron acceso a varias vistas dentro de la base de datos y quieres mapearlas en un DBContext, como ya la base de datos esta creada es Bueno que utilices la herramienta [Entity Data Model Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941658.aspx) para que puedas mapear esas vistas a entidades y tener un DBContext que accede a esos datos.

Esta respuesta esta basada en lo que puedo entender de tu pregunta. Si puedes ser mas especifico seria mucho major.